# Historical examples of replacing blood heir by impostor?

Tags: monarchy, inheritance

Both fiction and (contemporary at the time) conspiracy theories have many examples of "The king chooses to place a worthy replacement on the throne instead of his own not-qualified-to-rule offspring; with said impostor being presented to the populace as an actual heir by blood" trope.

**Were there any actual historical events that fit that pattern?** If there were many, who was the latest known?

Just to be clear, I'm interested in cases where (almost) everyone was told that the "heir" was indeed a child of the monarch, **at the monarch's wish**, and replacing an actual child (independently of said child surviving).

This does not include an usurper (like [LzheDmitry I](http://russia.rin.ru/guides_e/6919.html)) who claimed blood relation to the previous king without being acknowledged by that monarch himself.

Comment: Can't help but think of Catherine the Great, Tsarina of all the Russias, even though she was a wife and not a child. She was born and raised in a minor German noble family, and became the strongest *man* in all Russia. By all the rules and laws of the time she was clearly an imposter, yet through a combination of good timing, playing her cards well, and the hatred and contempt with which her husband was held she succeeded.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - "[imposter](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/imposter)" - "One who engages in deception **under an assumed name or identity**" implies that the woman who Russians called Catherine wasn't actually the wife of the Tsar. Which wasn't the case Catherine, AFAIK.

Comment: Interesting interpretation point - does *imposter* mean she was an unknown posing as Catherine the legitimate Tsarina, or posing as the legitimate Tsarina while undeniably being Catherine, the German of minor noble birth with **zero** claim to the Russian monarchy? I believe the context and wording of the question suggests the latter interpretation as applicable.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - Again, imposter implies pretending to be some other person. NOT holding a post under your own name, whether illegitimately or legitimately. Now, if Catherine held the post by pretending to be an **offspring** of Romanoffs (as opposed to a wife), that'd be an imposter; but I don't recall her doing so.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: from Wikipedia: "Catherine, although not descended from any previous Russian emperor, succeeded her husband as Empress Regnant. She followed the precedent established when Catherine I (born in the lower classes in the Swedish East Baltic territories) succeeded her husband Peter the Great in 1725.====
Historians debate Catherine's technical status, seeing her as a Regent or as a usurper, tolerable only during the minority of her son, Grand Duke Paul". Note that there's no dispute that she legitimately ascended to the throne in 1762.

Comment: There are many known [false Royal heritage claims](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_impostors#False_Royal_Heritage_Claims), but you seek cases where the parent supported or instigated the claim. I am skeptical that could occur in a heredity monarchy, where every move of the Monarch and those in line are watched. Furthermore you ask the impossible: it succeeded and yet was discovered.

Comment: @andy256 - there are always witnesses to things. Who tend to leave memoirs. Or genetic research. I don't see it as even remotely impossible to discover.

Comment: @andy256 What?! The Education of Little Tree was written by an imposter? This is a sad day indeed.

Comment: @RazieMah Perhaps the appropriate response is "Which is reasonable." :-)

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - I think the term you are looking for is "Pretender" not "Impostor"

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's an example of this in fiction?

Comment: @ssdecontrol - Various versions of Man in the Iron Mask, as an example

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Funny you should mention Catherine the Great -- I was thinking of Pugachev and all the Peter III impostors that popped up after she overthrew him. Not that Peter had any say in the matter -- he was dead.

Answer (score 1):

Sweden in 1810 - 1818.  The monarch legally adopted a French general as the official heir.  It took generations for the resulting rift between dynastic factions to be healed by a royal marriage.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Bernadotte

Comment: But Bernadotte was not claiming to be a different person that was an actual heir.

Answer (score 1):

It was often alleged that a disliked monarch was not who he claimed to be, that his alleged parents, despairing of having real children, pretended to have a child that was really unrelated.  Thus the births of royal children were often very public with many high ranking witnesses, and yet despite that a monarch's enemies would continue to claim that he was a false child.

Examples: Emperor Frederick II and King James VIII and III aka The Old Pretender.

Comment: I cannot help but be reminded of the "birthers" of Twenty-First century United States.